# Oauth authorization in app browser - 403 disallowed_useragent error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, oauth, google-oauth

Is there any workaround that allows login via a popup when a user tries to use a web application in another application browser such as fb messenger or linkedin? I am looking for a workaround for the `403 disallowed_useragent` error when they try to log in. Do you know of any solution that will allow the user to log in? (Other than one that requires the user to enter the address in a real browser). I am using the signInWithPopup method.

[image]

On the Internet, I could not find anything that could meet my requirements.

Comment: Any time something is rejected for security reasons, a workaround is not possible. Otherwise, you would be "hacking" the application in a way that compromises the security of the individual using it, and that would be bad (and also probably shut down very quickly).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oauth2 consent screen must be opened in the system browser.    It can't be open in a WebView from within another application

There is no way around this